# How can I split one string into two variables in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a string `SVchnsSoQQjr5kafygOh,,,Skyrim` and I'm trying to put the first 'string' into a variable, the 'Skyrim' into another variable and remove the ',,,'

I've tried `.substr()`

Expected output:

```
str = 'SVchnsSoQQjr5kafygOh,,,Skyrim'

strOne = 'SVchnsSoQQjr5kafygOh'
strTwo = 'Skyrim'
```

Comment: Remember: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. So many workflows of JavaScript still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` is your friend

```js
console.log('SVchnsSoQQjr5kafygOh,,,Skyrim'.split(',,,'));
```

To have two string variables assigned:

```js
const foo = 'SVchnsSoQQjr5kafygOh,,,Skyrim'.split(',,,');

const [str1, str2] = foo;
console.log(str1, str2);
```